# Browser-side JavaScript components to build on. Modularization, JQuery-friendly

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks

I need a tool on the client side to build a feature-rich application with JavaScript. Server-side is Flask (Python) if that is relevant. I don't want to use an MVC/UI framework on the client side (no backbone, angular, react, etc.)

I need just some simple things, like:

- Modularization. It should help me do normal programming without messing with JS's prototypes. It doesn't need to provide full OOP, just a way to program conventionally
- JQuery and/or Underscore-friendly. It should include those as dependencies or know of their existence
- About routing/readable URLs. I think that's an easy part so it's not necessary

With this requirements fulfilled I'm going to build a client side framework for declarative UI (+layouts/widgets) and any other thing an application would require

I'd want to emphasize that I don't like MVC as it is implemented in WWW and I don't need a feature rich UI framework with widgets. I hope my requirements are not too bold. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm thinking about extending Dojo or QooxDoo while throwing away all the rich functionality. KnockoutJS is also an option as a base, but I find it rather specific to the trending MVC structure. This is to share my attempts.